# Convert/Display ODK GeoShape to R

Tags: r, open-data-kit

After downloading data from an ODK form (hosted on ONA.io) and importing it into an R dataframe, all the fields are neatly parsed but for a column which contains spatial data.
Here is the first element of that column:

```
"18.774945 102.224942 294.0 4.9; 18.775019999999998 102.224842 295.0 4.7; 18.775105999999997 102.224795 296.0 4.7; 18.775204 102.22475399999999 296.0 4.7; 18.775278 102.22469799999999 298.0 4.7; 18.775334 102.224684 298.0 4.7; 18.775423 102.224648 300.0 4.7; 18.775482 102.224617 302.0 4.7; 18.775502 102.224603 302.0 4.7; 18.775563 102.224565 303.0 4.7; 18.775617999999998 102.224526 301.0 4.7; 18.775703999999998 102.224491 302.0 6.374369; 18.775775 102.224509 303.0 4.7; 18.775802 102.22451799999999 304.0 4.585183; 18.775819 102.224553 306.0 4.7; 18.775824 102.22455699999999 306.0 4.7; 18.775842 102.22457899999999 306.0 4.7; 18.775893999999997 102.224623 307.0 4.7; 18.77601 102.224623 309.0 4.7; 18.776094999999998 102.224702 311.0 4.7; 18.776204 102.22478 311.0 4.7; 18.776287999999997 102.224864 310.0 4.7; 18.776353 102.224925 310.0 4.7; 18.776442 102.22501799999999 314.0 4.7; 18.776522 102.225044 313.0 4.7; 18.776581 102.22508599999999 313.0 4.7; 18.776649 102.225133 315.0 4.7; 18.77665 102.22520899999999 314.0 4.7; 18.776629 102.22524899999999 314.0 4.7; 18.776594 102.225319 315.0 4.7; 18.776557999999998 102.22533999999999 316.0 4.7; 18.776487 102.225397 316.0 4.9; 18.776442 102.225476 317.0 5.6967044; 18.776433 102.225522 318.0 4.7; 18.77644 102.225568 318.0 4.7; 18.776415999999998 102.225612 320.0 4.7; 18.776391 102.22562699999999 321.0 4.7; 18.776374 102.225659 323.0 5.796931; 18.776353999999998 102.22568799999999 324.0 5.0890145; 18.776339 102.225698 324.0 4.9; 18.776284 102.225701 325.0 4.7; 18.776221 102.225653 327.0 4.5327344; 18.776166 102.22568899999999 333.0 4.7; 18.776173999999997 102.22583 335.0 4.7; 18.776182 102.22587 338.0 4.7; 18.776196 102.225923 340.0 4.7; 18.776213 102.226006 342.0 4.7; 18.776228 102.22607099999999 342.0 4.7; 18.776205 102.22615499999999 344.0 4.7; 18.776161 102.226259 347.0 4.7; 18.776117 102.22634599999999 350.0 4.7; 18.776076 102.22638599999999 349.0 4.7; 18.776096 102.226467 347.0 4.7; 18.776082 102.226541 350.0 4.7; 18.776056999999998 102.226621 351.0 4.7; 18.776014 102.22659499999999 348.0 4.7; 18.775983 102.226582 348.0 4.7; 18.775927 102.226603 341.0 4.7; 18.77588 102.226591 338.0 4.7; 18.775819 102.22659399999999 335.0 5.4378524; 18.775748 102.22657199999999 331.0 4.7; 18.775616 102.226542 324.0 5.7470994; 18.775544 102.226492 322.0 4.7; 18.775481 102.22646399999999 320.0 4.7; 18.775382999999998 102.22642499999999 314.0 4.7; 18.775296 102.226428 309.0 4.7; 18.775230999999998 102.22641899999999 305.0 4.7; 18.775156 102.226396 303.0 4.7; 18.775136 102.226393 303.0 4.7; 18.775091 102.22632399999999 302.0 4.7; 18.775011 102.226255 301.0 5.9669514; 18.774976 102.22617 300.0 4.7; 18.774939 102.226103 299.0 4.7; 18.774883 102.22596399999999 300.0 4.7; 18.774797 102.225877 301.0 4.7; 18.774749 102.225826 300.0 4.7; 18.774701 102.225774 299.0 4.7; 18.774618999999998 102.22568199999999 297.0 4.7; 18.774548 102.22560299999999 295.0 4.7; 18.774513 102.225498 295.0 4.7; 18.774486 102.225387 293.0 6.4425826; 18.774471 102.225286 289.0 7.0244956; 18.774456 102.2252 287.0 6.6605177; 18.774449 102.225145 288.0 5.252501; 18.77452 102.225054 292.0 4.7; 18.774552999999997 102.22509199999999 293.0 4.7; 18.774601 102.22510899999999 299.0 4.7; 18.774638 102.225072 305.0 4.7; 18.774707 102.22504599999999 308.0 4.7; 18.774801 102.225015 310.0 4.7; 18.774846999999998 102.22502 311.0 4.7; 18.774886 102.225005 312.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774888 102.224998 311.0 4.7; 18.774945 102.224942 294.0 4.9"
```

There is a pattern of `LON, LAT, X, Y;` here with `X` likely to be the altitude and `Y` the accuracy threshold as described in [this other post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334525/convert-odk-geo-shape-to-geojson).

I would like to  to parse the data in a format easy to render with `leaflet::addPolygons()` or otherwise with `maptools` or `sp` package. It would be nice to have confirmation of what are `X` and `Y`.

I have looked for a solution on forum.getodk.org where there is [a discussion on the GeoShape/GeoPointData format](https://forum.getodk.org/t/make-geoshapedata-geopointdata-more-flexible-to-include-additional-geo-data/16861) but without success.

Comment: The definition of X ad Y is given in the Location section of the ODK documentation: https://docs.getodk.org/form-question-types/#location-widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string in that format the process to convert to a polygon could be:

1. Replace the semicolons with spaces.
2. Split the string on spaces to make a vector.
3. Reform the vector into a matrix with four columns.
4. Turn that matrix in a spatial polygon object.

The first three steps are all base R functions. For some string `s` in that format:

```
> sm = matrix(as.numeric(strsplit(gsub(";"," ",s)," +")[[1]]),ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
> head(sm)
         [,1]     [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 18.77494 102.2249  294  4.9
[2,] 18.77502 102.2248  295  4.7
[3,] 18.77511 102.2248  296  4.7
[4,] 18.77520 102.2248  296  4.7
```

To make a spatial polygon out of that I would use the `sf` package - these objects work with the `leaflet` package and are generally faster and cleaner than `sp` objects:

```
> library(sf)
> p1 = st_zm(st_polygon(list(sm)))
```

Without `st_zm` the resulting object will be an "XYZM" object, keeping the altitude and accuracy data - this can break some things so I've dropped it in the line above. `p1` is now an `XY` object.

If you have a data frame of these then loop over them, put them in an `st_sfc` vector and set the coordinate system to ESPG:4326. Wrap that all into a function. Like this...

```
library(sf)
odk_to_sf <- function(d, col){
    sms = lapply(d[[col]], function(geodata){
        matrix(
            as.numeric(
                strsplit(
                    gsub(";"," ",geodata)
                   ," +")[[1]])
           ,ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
    })
    p = lapply(sms, function(sm){st_zm(st_polygon(list(sm)))})
    d = st_as_sf(d, geom=st_sfc(p), crs=4326)
    d[[col]] = NULL
    d
}
```

Test, let's make a tiny data frame with some triangles in geodata:

```
s = c("0 0 0 1; 1 0 0 1; 1 1 0 1; 0 0 0 1;",
      "1 1 0 1; 1 2 0 1; 2 2 0 1; 1 1 0 1;")
df = data.frame(location=s, name=c("A","B"))
```

Convert:

```
> df = odk_to_sf(df,"location")

> df
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 2 ymax: 2
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
  name                           geom
1    A POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))
2    B POLYGON ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 1 1))
```

and plot:

> plot(df)

[image: two shaded triangles]

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! It was an easy adaptation to deal with unclosed polygons and to swap lat and lon for leaflet.